# How can I copy the whole content of a directory from raw resources to internal storage

Tags: android, html, android-resources, android-assets

I have an index.html file and some images displayed on this page stored in res/raw folder.

I need to open this file in android browser. So, I copy this file into sdcard.

But if i use R.raw.index the index file only copied other files are not copied. 
Since other html and images are not copied to sdcard: I don't see the images when I open index.html in browser.

Here is my current code to copy raw resource:

```
private File copyFile(int resourceId, String filename) {
        InputStream in = null; 
        OutputStream out = null;
        File outFile = null;
        try {
            in = mContext.getResources().openRawResource(resourceId);
            outFile = new File(mContext.getExternalFilesDir(null), filename);
            Log.d("TestHTML", "output file" +  outFile.getAbsolutePath());
            out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int read;
            while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
                out.write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            Log.e("TestHTML", "Failed to copy file", e);
        } finally {
            try {
                in.close();
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                in = null;
                out = null;
            } catch (Exception e){}
        }
        return outFile;
    }
```

And here is the layout of the res/raw folder

[image]

Can you give me a hint on how to copy the whole content of the res/raw directory to the internal storage ?

Comment: do you have a question to ask ?

Comment: I asked my question. wasn't you understand?

Comment: I don't see the question mark. When I read your question, here is the abstract that I can make : "I copy only one file from raw resources to internal storage and after the copy : only one file is copied to internal storage" (and so what's the question here ?) (you can also read this : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask )

Comment: Can you see my image? Inside raw folder i have other folders and files. But index.html file only copied to sdcard. So i can't get the image display and other pages links are not working

Comment: So I suggest you to improve your question with this title : "How can I copy the whole content of a directory from raw resources to internal storage ?"

Answer (score 1):

From the [android doc about the res/raw folder](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html):

> > Arbitrary files to save in their raw form. To open these resources with a raw InputStream, call Resources.openRawResource() with the resource ID, which is R.raw.filename.
> >
> > However, if you need access to original file names and file hierarchy, you might consider saving some resources in the assets/ directory (instead of res/raw/). Files in assets/ are not given a resource ID, so you can read them only using AssetManager.

Since you will use all this stuff in html : you need to keep an access by filename. **So don't put those files in `res/raw`. Put them in your `assets` folder**.

Once this is done you can copy all of them one by one and recursively to to internal storage.

The entry point to list files in some assets folder is `getAssets().list(path)` where `path` denote the path to the directory containing the `index.html`.

You also have to update your copyFile method to make it recursive and listing files from assets.